# django - reversing admin urls based on current admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

Here is my custom `ModelAdmin` class:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def foo(self, obj):
        ...
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (app_label, model_name), args=[obj.pk])
        ...
```

`foo` method provides a link to the change view of `obj`. The problem is that I want to have two different admin sites and use this custom ModelAdmin in both them. Therefore I need to reverse the url based on the current admin site. Any ideas on how to do so?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't be simpler:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def foo(self, obj):
        ...
        url = reverse('%s:%s_%s_change' % (self.admin_site.name, app_label, model_name), args=[obj.pk])
        ...
```